# How to speed up a gif in go?

Tags: go, encoding, gif, animated-gif

How do I speed up a gif like on [ezgif](https://ezgif.com/) using go ?

The total frame count after changing the speed is the same but upon opening the gif in any player the processed gif appears faster.
I am trying to build a pet meme generator clone. The only thing that I am stuck on is how do I speed the gif up.

The std lib in go is only able to slow down a gif and so I tried speeding up the input gif and only modifying the delay, but upon encoding it through the std lib, it was brought back to the original speed since the frame count is unchanged when its sped up.

**Edit: As pointed out by @harold, the delay between the frames of the new gif is different. Also the total frame count of my gif is 5. Any ideas as to why setting a delay of 2 speeds it up but something like 20 slows it and how do I control this speeding up ?**

Comment: How high was the new frame delay? There is a known (not very widely known) issue that many (but not all, also creating problems) GIF players will ignore small delays and default to some larger delay (such as 100ms or 20ms depending on the player).

Comment: @harold That seems to be it. The std lib says the delay of the sped up version is 2 (1/200th of a second) for all frames and I modified my output delay to the same and surprisingly the gif was sped up. Interestingly setting it to 20 slowed it as its supposed to. Thanks for your insight :D